# How do can I display a message after a checkbutton is clicked in Tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering how I can get a message to be shown after a checkbutton is clicked. Saying something like you chose 1-3. Any ideas?

```
     msg1 = f"How many pairs of shoes do you have?\n"
        self.text_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.text_widget.insert(END, msg1, 'person_text')
        self.text_widget.configure(state=DISABLED)
       
        var1 = tk.StringVar()
        box1 = tk.Checkbutton(self.window, variable = var1, offvalue="", onvalue="1-3", text = '1-3')
        
        var2 = tk.StringVar()
        box2 = tk.Checkbutton(self.window, variable = var2, offvalue="", onvalue="4-7", text = '4-7')
        
        var3 = tk.StringVar()
        box3 = tk.Checkbutton(self.window, variable = var3, offvalue="", onvalue="10+", text = '10+')
        
        self.text_widget.window_create("5.0", window = box1)
        self.text_widget.window_create("5.0", window = box2)
        self.text_widget.window_create("5.0", window = box3)
```

Comment: If the text is short, I usually edit the text inside the button to do this type of work. Or if it is too long, I would add an invisible text widget somewhere and show it and change its text to display the message.

Comment: Do you want a dialog window to appear whenever the user makes a selection, or do you just want a bit of text to appear in the same window to show the message?

Comment: Change this var1 = tk.StringVar() to var1 = IntVar(). Do then same thing  for checkboxes.

Comment: I would like text to appear in the same window once a selection is made.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using the `ttk.Radiobutton` widget instead of a `tk.Checkbutton` since these options seem mutually exclusive. Also, you'll only need one `tk.StringVar()` to store the selection value this way.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm
from tkinter import ttk


def on_btn_change() -> None:
    """This function is called when a selection is made"""
    selection=btn_var.get()  # fetch the selected value
    tkm.showinfo(  # show the dialog message
        title='Selection Made',
        message=f'You selected {selection}'
    )


btn_var = tk.StringVar()  # variable to store the button selection
buttons = ['1-3', '4-6', '7-9', '10+']  # button names / values

for name in buttons:  # create buttons
    ttk.Radiobutton(
        root,  # or whatever your tk.Tk() instance is called
        text=name,
        value=name,
        variable=btn_var,  # store the selection in 'btn_var'
        command=on_btn_change,  # this function is called each time the button changes
        state=tk.NORMAL  # not required, but it doesn't hurt anything
    ).pack()  # remember to 'pack()' or nothing will show up!
```

Edit - just wanted to say that this is only an example and obviously won't run as-is. Also, if you're building your Tk app using classes (which you seem to be - good on ya), then you'll need to add `self` as a parameter to `on_btn_change()`, e.g.: `def on_btn_change(self) -> None: . . .` and you'll likely want to change `btn_var` and `buttons` to `self.btn_var` and `self.buttons`, respectively.

Comment: Any time - happy to help!